# Dual kernel (distribution:- Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04) installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I installed both Win10 and ubuntu 14.04 in my dell Latitude 3460(Vostro) laptop with the help of following steps:-

1. First i clean the disk using cmd at the boot time.
2. Then i install Win10 first.
3. While installing Win10 I make the 4 primary partitions(2 for windows and 2 for Linux-swap,root)
4. Then i install Ubuntu.

The problem is that while i a restarting my laptop Windows is not booting it is strucking at the time of booting and when i start window after shut down then it is booting without any problem.
I dont know whats the actual problem

Comment: Can you elaborate a little about "strucking at the time of booting." Does it freeze up right after you select Windows 10 from the GRUB menu? Are you getting any error messages or does the screen just freeze?

Comment: @n8te yes it freezes up when i select win10 from the GRUB menu no it is showing purple color screen with lines and dots

Comment: I had a similar situation with my laptop. It would freeze on a green screen with lines. I kept having to force shutdown. What I finally realized is that it was installing Windows updates during that frozen green screen but just not displaying the Windows Updating screen. Finally I let it sit there for 20 minutes on that frozen screen and suddenly Windows loaded because it had finished installing the updates. It seems like it's not doing anything during that frozen part but it really was updating. Maybe you're having the same issue.

Comment: but why it goes in that position when i restart the pc

Comment: When you boot into Windows that is when Windows checks for the new updates and installs them. And then it finishes the update installation when you restart. When you force shut it down when faced with that seemingly frozen screen, it breaks that continuation of the update that started before your initial restart, so then Windows boots up fine.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining it well but just give it a try. Let it sit 15 or 20 minutes at that frozen screen and see if it eventually boots. If it does you won't have that problem on the next restart since Windows will be up to date.

Comment: Ya you are right i also experienced this thing even not 15-20 min it hardly took 5 min. May be your observation is right

Comment: My laptop has an HDD so it took longer for the updates but if you have an SSD than 5 minutes sounds about right. I bet next time you restart it will boot right up.

Comment: Actually i am not confident about it that some updates windows might installing in background because it happens every time.

Comment: I think it only happened every time is because you forced shut it down thinking it was frozen so every time it kept trying to install the same updates again. That's what was happening with me until I figured it out.

Comment: No every time i wait now because i know it will start after 5-6 min so i wait for it